# Two columns within an ISNULL function in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is for individuals and the other is for their company.

Each table has a column for locale, this is mandatory for the company, but not for the individual. The idea seems to be that if the individual doesn't set a preference, they are assumed to be in the locale of their company.

I would like to select the locale for the individual, using the company default if the individual locale is null and I thought of doing the following (which I don't think is possible in MySql)...

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(individual.Locale, company.Locale) `Locale`
FROM
    individual
INNER JOIN
    company ON company.CompanyId = individual.CompanyId
WHERE
    individual.IndividualId = 1
```

Is there a nice way to do this - or am I just going to end up sending both Locale's back and making the decision in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [**`COALESCE()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which returns the first non-NULL value among its arguments. This function can also be used in most other RDBMS like [**SQL-Server**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), [**Oracle 9**](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php), [**Postgres 8**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(individual.Locale, company.Locale) AS Locale
FROM
    individual
INNER JOIN
    company ON company.CompanyId = individual.CompanyId
WHERE
    individual.IndividualId = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much had it, what you want is `IFNULL()`

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(individual.Locale, company.Locale) `Locale`
FROM
    individual
INNER JOIN
    company ON company.CompanyId = individual.CompanyId
WHERE
    individual.IndividualId = 1
```

Comment: +1 as this is a great answer - I had to go with COALESCE in the end as it will work on other databases too and performs about the same unless you use it as part of a sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [CASE...WHEN...THEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
       WHEN individual.Locale IS NULL THEN company.Locale
       ELSE individual.Locale
    END) 'Locale'
FROM
    individual
INNER JOIN
    company ON company.CompanyId = individual.CompanyId
WHERE
    individual.IndividualId = 1
```

Comment: This will not work, Change it into: `CASE WHEN individual.Locale IS  NULL THEN ...`

Comment: Yes, because `CASE expression WHEN` checks for equality and `NULL=NULL` is not `True` (unfortunately :)